# redis: hmset expire, but hgetall can get subkey info

Tags: python, redis

python code:

```
value = {'sct': 's', 'scn': 'A', 'fct': 'd', 'fcn': 'K', 'bet_value':10}
res = rc.hmset(key, value) 
rc.expire(key, 3600)
```

3600 seconds later

```
rc.hgetall(key)
```

result:
    {'sct': 's', 'scn': 'A', 'fct': 'd', 'fcn': 'K'}

```
rc.ttl(key) has no result
```

The question is that the "key" should be expired after 3600s, but I can still get info with the command "hetall".
The ttl command return None, according to the document it should be -2 or -1
What's wrong? anybody can help?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? It would help enhance comprehension to help you.

Comment: ok, I have just done as what you say, thanks

Comment: Which redis version you are using?

Comment: Is it possible that the key was actually touched and modified between your setting the expiration and when you tested with HGETALL?  I ask because the "bet_value" field of your hash seems to be missing from the result of the HGETALL.